# Change input fields order from vertical to horizontal?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my form:

```
<form novalidate class="form-group" ng-hide="tab==1">
    Reviews Min: <input type="number" ng-init="revNum=0" class="form-control" min="0" step="10" ng-model="revNum" /> 
    Min Price: <input type="number" ng-init="minNum=0" class="form-control" min="0" step="1000" ng-model="minNum" />
    Max Price: <input type="number" ng-init="maxNum=0" class="form-control" min="0" step="1000" ng-model="maxNum" />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateNumArray(revNum, minNum, maxNum)">Filter</button>
</form>
```

Here my `style.css`:

```
input {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Here is what I get in my browser:

[image]

What shoould I change to make it look something like this:

[image]

Comment: You should be using `<label>` as well ideally.

Comment: this may work try `.form-group > .form-control, .form-group > .btn-primary {display: inline-block;}`

Comment: @MichaelVayvala maybe this is what you want, check that demo - http://www.bootply.com/usy0b1IwS3

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few options..

http://www.bootply.com/cFtRhRycYE

One uses `col-*` to create a single row of inputs, but this has the usual gutter spacing between each input. If you want it inline with less spacing you can do something like..

```
<form novalidate="" class="form-inline" ng-hide="tab==1">
  <div class="form-group">Reviews Min:<br><input type="number" ng-init="revNum=0" class="form-control" min="0" step="10" ng-model="revNum"> </div>
  <div class="form-group">Min Price:<br><input type="number" ng-init="minNum=0" class="form-control" min="0" step="1000" ng-model="minNum"> </div>
  <div class="form-group">Max Price:<br><input type="number" ng-init="maxNum=0" class="form-control" min="0" step="1000" ng-model="maxNum"> </div>
  <div class="form-group"><br><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateNumArray(revNum, minNum, maxNum)">Filter</button> </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Exactly the way it should be done...especially the 'label' way. +1

Comment: using `<p>` tags is more semantically correct than `<div>` to wrap each control, as per w3c spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element but that's just me being picky, good examples!

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap sets the display of inputs to `block` with`100%` width. You can override it by appling

```
 input {
  display:inline-block !important;
  width: 100px !important;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gwkzzg9e/)

Answer (score 1):

use `inline-block`, `inline-block` or `float` on the `input` elements - experiment with these to see the different results, it's a good way to learn!

Answer (score 1):

**Bootply - [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/rytafh2UZi)**

you should use a extra `span` tag to warp your `input` and text (not the button) and apply `inline-block;`

**HTML:**

```
<form novalidate="" class="form-group" ng-hide="tab==1">
  <span class="form-span">Reviews Min: <input type="number" ng-init="revNum=0" class="form-control" min="0" step="10" ng-model="revNum"></span>
  <span class="form-span">Min Price: <input type="number" ng-init="minNum=0" class="form-control" min="0" step="1000" ng-model="minNum"></span>
  <span class="form-span">Max Price: <input type="number" ng-init="maxNum=0" class="form-control" min="0" step="1000" ng-model="maxNum"></span>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateNumArray(revNum, minNum, maxNum)">Filter</button>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
.form-span {
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```